# Can I trade exhibit items from the Curse of the Dark Pharaoh expansion with other investigators?

Tags: arkham-horror, arkham-horror-curse-of-dark-pharaoh

Do exhibit items from the Curse of the Dark Pharaoh expansion count as tradable items?

Comment: Yea I wasn't sure about how to tag this. It seemed like the convention was to tie it to the base game, not use two separate tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Exhibit items can be traded like other items.

From the [Curse of the Dark Pharaoh rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/f9/be/f9bed12e-4dac-43bc-a7c6-951c3afefe61/curse_dark_pharoah_rules.pdf):

> The Exhibit Item cards represent the ancient Egyptian artifacts
>   brought to Arkham as part of the "Legacy of the
>   Pharaohs" museum exhibit. They are similar to Unique Items,
>   but have no monetary value and can only be gained through
>   Arkham, Other World, and Exhibit encounters.

This states that they function the same as Unique Items, but does not disclude them being traded.

Also from the [Complete Arkham Horror FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/FAQs/Complete_Arkham_FAQ.pdf) (page 4/5):

> **Q:** Exactly where, when, and what can investigators
>   trade?
>
> **A:**
>   They may trade Common Items, Unique Items, Spells,
>   the Patrol Wagon, the Deputy’s Revolver, Exhibit Items
>   [CotDP], Rail Passes [DH], and Money.